# Li-ion BMS 2S3P wiring to a 2S BMS

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, parallel, bms

I'd like to seriously increase the capacity of my pack by adding more cells in parallel whist maintaining 8.4v from these 4.2v/3500mAh 18650 batteries.

I'd like this scalable so I could potentially have 2S4P for example.

Would the following work with just one of those common 2S BMS's?

[image]

Comment: If you are going to just increase the capacity it's ok, if you want increase current drain it's not so good. Pairing the batteries connected in parallel you can improve the current imbalance (parallel batt. with similar R_ser). You are limited with 8A drain of this BMS, btw.